# Why Google Chrome invalidate a valid WebExtension's manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome-extension

[Chrome invalidate a valid manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv6cW.png)

While importing valid unpacked extension.
(manifest confirmed by https://manifest-validator.appspot.com/)

this error appears, and the extension do not get loaded.

> Only one of 'browser_action', 'page_action', and 'app' can be
>   specified.

Manifest does not contain duplication of the neither mentioned in the error.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "addon@example.com",
      "strict_min_version": "42.0"
    }
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.js", "my-background.js"],
    "page": "my-background.html"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "userInterface/browser_action_button/airplay_icon.svg",
    "default_title": "LightDictionary",
    "default_popup": "userInterface/browser_action_button/popup.html"
  },

  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
      }
    }
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "exclude_matches": ["*://developer.mozilla.org/*"],
      "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
      "js": ["borderify.js"]
    }
  ],

  "default_locale": "en",

  "description": "none",

  "icons": {
    "48": "userInterface/browser_action_button/airplay_icon.svg",
    "96": "userInterface/browser_action_button/airplay_icon.svg"
  },

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "LightDictionary",

  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "userInterface/browser_action_button/airplay_icon.svg",
      "38": "userInterface/browser_action_button/airplay_icon.svg"
    },
    "default_title": "LightDictionary",
    "default_popup": "userInterface/browser_action_button/popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": ["webNavigation"],

  "version": "0.1",

  "web_accessible_resources": ["images/my-image.png"]
}
```

Comment: It means if you have a browser action, you can't have a page action, and vice versa.

Comment: General tip - if your extension is applicable to all pages - use browser action. If usage limited to some pages - use page action.

Answer (score 1):

I have talked to Mozilla MDN maintainer on their IRC channel and I came to the conclusion, that the so called "cross-browser extension" manifest.json published on:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json

Was incompatible with Chrome, and only works on the Firefox browser due to:

Chrome has strict check on the manifest, and the way Chrome handles manifest differs from the way Firefox does it. Chrome is slow to adopt technologies that are supported by the Firefox.

So, the only way to make the manifest cross-browser compatible:  is

1. to take [quick manifest.json example suggested by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json)
2. load it into Chrome ([chrome://extensions](http://chrome://extensions), Turn on developer mode, Load Unpacked)
3. check the errors and remove what is asked by the chrome.

Things to keep in mind:

- Chrome does not support .svg format icons, this leads to not showing specified icon. While Firefox does support it, it is suggestive to not use svg for a cross browser extension.

Futher comment to read: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/06/cross-browser-extensions-available-now-in-firefox/#comment-21268

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one of the properties that it specifies in the error.

> Only one of 'browser_action', 'page_action', and 'app' can be specified.

You have both a **browser_action** property & a **page_action** property in your json object.

Remove one of these from the object to fix it.